# How to instantiate a global smart pointer variable?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

How do I instantiate

```
unique_ptr<int[]> sums;
```

in

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = //get from args
    sums(new int[n]);
}
```

? It gives me the following compile-time error

> error C2247: 'std::default_delete<_Ty>::operator ()' not accessible
>   because 'std::unique_ptr>' uses
>   'private' to inherit from 'std::_Unique_ptr_base<_Ty,_Dx,true>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be confused about C++'s constructor call syntax.

If you say

```
unique_ptr<int[]> sums(new int[n]);
```

That constructs a new object called `sums`, calling the constructor with the pointer to the int array.

If you say

```
unique_ptr<int[]> sums;
sums(new int[n]);
```

It constructs `sums` using the 0 argument constructor in the first line, then in the second line tries to call `unique_ptr<int[]>::operator()(int*)` (ie, the function call operator) on the `sums` object. This does not exist, which gives you the error.

As dauphic's answer says, the function you're looking for is called `reset`:

```
sums.reset(new int[n]);
```

(You might be wondering why something so silly as a function call operator exists. It's there to allow you to create [an object that can be called like a function, but passed around like a value.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function))

Comment: I didn't realize that it could be a constructor call you have in the first code snippet. I just thought that it is just a way of expressing a smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to invoke `sums` as if it's a function, which it's not. The internals of `std::unique_ptr` make the error message confusing/misleading.

If you want to initialize what `sums` points to, you should use the `reset` function.

```
sums.reset(new int[n]);
```

Comment: Ah, right. And is there an easy way how to set all cells of the array to some default value?

Comment: You can use `std::fill` to fill the array, but it's better to use `std::vector` instead of a C array.